# How to get the $2$ angles between two vectors?

Tags: trigonometry, vectors

> [image]

I have the following problem: there is a vector $\bf{v}$ in the blue plane and a point $P$ somewhere in the same coordinate frame. I can compute the vector $\bf{OP}$. Now the question is how do I get the angles $\alpha$ and $\beta$ between the vector $\bf{v}$ and the vector $\bf{OP}$? $\alpha$ should lie in the same plane and $\beta$ should be perpendicular to it.

Does someone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $O$ be the origin and the equation of the plane be $ax+by+cz=0$

Find the foot of the perpendicular of $P~(p_x,p_y,p_z) $ on the plane and let it be $M~(m_x,m_y,m_z) $. You may take help of the following result for finding that:

$$ \frac{m_x-p_x}{a} = \frac{m_y-p_y}{b} = \frac{m_z-p_z}{c} = -\frac{ap_x+bp_y+cp_z}{a^2+b^2+c^2}$$

Once you have obtained the coordinates of $M$, you can find $ \alpha $ and $ \beta $ using the relations:

$$ \cos \beta = \dfrac{\overrightarrow{OP} \cdot \overrightarrow{OM}}{|\overrightarrow{OP}||\overrightarrow{OM}|}$$
$$ \cos \alpha = \dfrac{\overrightarrow{OV} \cdot \overrightarrow{OM}}{|\overrightarrow{OV}||\overrightarrow{OM}|}$$